# Interrupt blocking network IO without closing the socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I read from a stream created by `Socket.getInputStream()`. When I use it, it blocks until it gets new data(exactly what it should). Now I need the stream to read something (see below). But when I start a new read it will give me unspecified output(or not?). My question is:

How can I interrupt the actual read, so I can use the read method?

Details: I connect to a server and send commands to it. From time to time the server sends messages to my client (event notifications), which I need to register. I want to be able to send commands while I'm waiting for this messages. When I send a command the answer to this command is read from the stream. And here is the problem: I'm still listening to the messages while I try to read my answer. So I need something that interrupts the current read.

Comment: when you are working with blocking streams, you need to use _separate threads_ for reading and writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with stopping the event processor from reading is that you introduce a race condition: What happens if the server sends an event right after you terminated the read? The "response" that you read would wind up being an event.

The proper way to do this is to do all your reading, both events and responses, in one place and handle the responses like an event also. Right before you send a command, register a listener for the response, then send the command. When the reading thread sees a response, have it find the proper listener and notify it that the response has been received.

Comment: Never thought about adding a listerner for command parsing. I now turned off my reads from the current thread and moved them to a listener. Thank you for the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest, best way to handle this IMO is to use an asynchronous listener with event callbacks. [DataFetcher is an implementation](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) (Also see [Timeout](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/TimeOut.java) and [PartialReadException](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/PartialReadException.java), dependencies in the same project/package, and [IOUtils](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/IOUtils.java), which has capabilities to directly connect a `FetcherListener` with an `InputStream`)